# Converting Array to bulk Create in nodejs with Sequelize

Tags: mysql, angularjs, node.js

This is my req.body json data from angularjs controller:

```
{ 
    phoneno: [ 
               { id: 1, gsm: '123457801',  firstName: 'Mohamed',  lastName: 'Sameer'},
               { id: 2, gsm: '123450987',  firstName: 'Hameed',   lastName: 'Basha' } 
             ],
    sender: 'ifelse',
    message: 'Hello Test' 

}
```

i want to get gsm values from req.body

I want to make the above structure into this type:

```
[{phoneno:123457801;sender:'ifelse';message:'Hello Test'},{phoneno:123450987;sender:ifelse;message:'Hello Test'}]
```

then only i am able to insert in mysql.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think it will helpful to you!...

```js
var body={ 
    phoneno: [ 
               { id: 1, gsm: '123457801',  firstName: 'Mohamed',  lastName: 'Sameer'},
               { id: 2, gsm: '123450987',  firstName: 'Hameed',   lastName: 'Basha' } 
             ],
    sender: 'ifelse',
    message: 'Hello Test' 

};
var new_req_body=[];
for(var i=0;i<body.phoneno.length;i++){

var new_arr={
            sender:body.sender,
            message:body.message,
            phoneno:body.phoneno[i].gsm
          };
new_req_body.push(new_arr);
}
console.log(new_req_body);
```

Comment: @kaiaiselvan you there? another problem

Comment: post it as a separate question and send me a link